# How to setup / install gettext on cpanel?

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, gettext

I've searched a lot, but I got confused how to install gettext on cpanel, actually I've no **easyapache** in my control panel , I just have **apache spamassassin** and **apache handlers**

I need to install gettext which is **"gettext - is missing!!"**

Please guide me step by step very basic that how I can install it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems no one knows how to solve this issue. awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

Without root access you can NOT install gettext on your server. On cPanel server you will have to run easyapache to compile gettext with php.

Comment: So, how to get access to root server when I've no easyapache in my control panel??

Comment: Do you have VPS or dedicated server or you have purchased a shared hosting plan?